# Changes to Array not reflecting in program?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object, multidimensional-array

I was trying to make a battleship clone but ended up running into one problem. I made a BattleShipGrid class that had two 2D arrays, one for each player. The array called p1/p2grid holds their ship and the locations the other player has shot at. The second array called p1/p2fire is the one that shows only where they shot, and not where the enemy ship is, though they can see where they’ve hit it. Im having a problem where I want to print player 1's fire grid after them firing to show if they missed or not. But each time I print player 1's fire grid it still sets everything as 0, like they never even fired on anything. I made 1 a  miss and 3 a hit and 2 to represent the location of a ship. 
Here is my code in my main:

```
    boolean player1Turn = true;
    if (player1Turn) {
        fire = grid.fireAtPlayerTwo(x, y);
    } else {
        fire = grid.fireAtPlayerOne(x, y);
    }

    if (fire == 0) {
        System.out.println("Miss!");
    } else if (fire == 2) {
        System.out.println("=====================================");
        System.out.println("Hit!");

        if (player1Turn) {
            System.out.println(grid.printP1Fire());/* printing regular old empty array filled with zeros like when a player just starts and hasn't fired on anything.*/
        } else {
            System.out.println(grid.printP2Fire());
        }
        System.out.println("=====================================");
    }
```

Here is my methods that I called when firing on the other player( fire at player one and fire at player two do the same thing but are named different  ) :

```
    int Empty = 0;
    public int fireAtPlayerTwo ( int x, int y)
    {
        int result = p2Grid[x][y];
        if (result == EMPTY) {
            p1Grid[x][y] = MISS;/* This should change the value in p1Grid at that coordinate  but it is not refelcting back in the main*/
            p2Fire[x][y] = MISS;
        } else if (result == SHIP) {
            p1Grid[x][y] = HIT;
            p2Fire[x][y] = HIT;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: `System.out.println(grid.printP1Fire());/* printing regular old empty array filled with zeros like when a player just starts and hasn't fired on anything.*` - so why not show **this** code?

Comment: Also does `EMPTY` equal `2` ?  Otherwise you logic seems **wrong**

Comment: Empty is equal to 0. I just added it. What would be wrong about my logic?

Comment: In `fireAtPlayerTwo` you have `int result = p2Grid[x][y];` and then comment on code that is not working when `result == EMPTY` then you `return result`  then assign the return value to `fire` and then check `else if(fire == 2)` - so is `p2Grid[x][y];` `EMPTY` or `2` - it can't be both

Comment: I suggest you use a debugger and see what is happening

Comment: Empty is just equal to the int 0. So in other words  p1Grid[x][y] and  p2Grid[x][y] can both be equal to empty(0). They can not be equal to both 0 and 2 at the same time.